# Toggle enable/disable Ethernet adapter from CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, netsh

I'm trying to create a *.bat* file which can enable/disable my ethernet adapter, but I don't have much knowledge about coding or the cmd syntax. I was thinking about using the *netsh* command in something like:

```
IF " ~Ethernet adapter is enabled~ " GOTO :disable ELSE GOTO :enable

:disable
    netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disabled
        
:enable
    netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enabled
```

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already familiar with the `netsh interface` command, why don't you use it?

```
netsh interface show interface "Ethernet" |find "Connected" >nul && (
  echo connected - disconnecting...
  netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disabled
) || (
  echo disconnected - connecting
  netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enabled
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In above solution it disconnects and connects the internet connection so I improvised like this to Toggle enable and disable Ethernet adapter and this is working perfectly for me.
This code disables adapter if it is enabled and enables if it is disabled.

```
netsh interface show interface "Ethernet" |find "Disabled" >nul && (
  echo disabled - enabling...
  netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enabled
) || (
  echo enabled - disabling
  netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disabled
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It helps users a great deal if you add a bit of explanation of how your code answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://www.action1.com/kb/disabling-or-enabling-network-adapter-in-Windows-with-WMIC.html#:%7E:text=the%20Netsh%20Command-,Open%20a%20command%20prompt%20as%20an%20administrator%3A%20one%20way%20is,want%20to%20disable%20or%20enable.) shows multiple ways to do it.

The one which I used is below.

1. run the command to get the name of your interface, which requires a restart.

   **netsh interface show interface**

This lists down something like this.

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wi-Fi 
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Ethernet 4 
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Ethernet
```

2. Below are the commands to restart the Wifi adapter. Use the name, listed in point 1.

   **netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" disable**

   **netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" enable**