# How to restart computer after network disconnected?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I try to restart computer via CMD.
I can only find and check program which not running >> restarting computer.
But I cannot find the solution to check network >> restarting computer.

My code is:

```
:start
tasklist | find "%proc%" >nul && (
echo %proc% is OK
timeout /t %time%
goto :start ) || (
echo ERROR! RESTART WINDOWS!...
timeout /t 30
shutdown.exe /r /t 00
)
```

Please help.

Comment: IPCONFIG is the command that will give details about the status of network interfaces - perhaps look for "disconnected", or perhaps you can run PING and check for the lack of the string "reply from"

Comment: @CaiusJard ever seen `ping` responding "Reply from localhost. Destination unreachable"? Better search for `TTL=`

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47957701/2152082)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [ping](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) a remote address (in this case google.com) and use errorLevel to determine wether you're connected. The below code will check the connection every second and if it detects no connection, immediately restart.

```
:start
ping -n 1 google.com >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto noConnection
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
goto :start

:noConnection
echo ERROR: No connection found, restarting!
shutdown /r
```