# How to combine two statement in one batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, netsh

I'm new to batch files and searching how these batch files can be combined into one:
On the first click, it will set the LAN adapter to DHCP and when click again, it will set a Static IP in the LAN adapter.

**DHCP.bat**

```
@echo off

: Disable Static IP/Enable DHCP    Remove DNS     Enable NICs
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
netsh int ip set address "%%j" dhcp >nul 2>&1
netsh int ip set dns "%%j" dhcp >nul 2>&1
netsh interface set interface name="%%j" admin=enabled >nul 2>&1
)

ipconfig /flushdns >nul 2>&1
```

**Static.bat**

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" address=192.x.x.x mask=255.x.x.0 gate=192.x.x.x static
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Ethernet" static 192.x.x.x validate=no
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=192.x.x.x index=2 validate=no
```

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this just for your own specific PC, as currently configured? Your codes appear to assume that the PC has a wired network device enabled, its status, its name, its index, and I'd guess the gateway and static IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Yes, I based my Static IPs on computer names. For example if I have STG101 as computer name, then my IP would be 192.x.x.101

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47960393/2152082) help?

Comment: @Stephan, Thanks, it is similar to what I wanted the batch file to do, but it only disabled-enable the Network adapter not setting the adapter to DHCP or Static once triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same logic from the mentioned post in the comments.

Check if DHCP is enabled or not and act accordingly:

```
@echo off 
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
  netsh interface ipv4 show addresses "%%j" |find "Yes" && (
    REM DHCP is currently enabled for this adapter, so set to fixed:
    netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" address=192.x.x.x mask=255.x.x.0 gate=192.x.x.x static
    netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Ethernet" static 192.x.x.x validate=no
    netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=192.x.x.x index=2 validate=no
  ) || (
    REM DHCP is currently disabled for this adapter, so set to DHCP:
    netsh int ip set address "%%j" dhcp >nul 2>&1
    netsh int ip set dns "%%j" dhcp >nul 2>&1
    netsh interface set interface name="%%j" admin=enabled >nul 2>&1
  )
)
ipconfig /flushdns >nul 2>&1
```

(untested; Remember to adapt the string `Yes` to your language)

**Attention:** this works fine if you have only one network adapter, but pay attention if you have more than one (for example LAN and WLAN or two LAN adapters). You need to take care of unique addresses!